# Leave 'git diff' result in the terminal

Tags: git

I use Git in the terminal. When I have to make some changes, I use `git diff` to see what I have changed. I'd like that output result to stay in the terminal, so I can review it after I press <kbd>Q</kbd>, since when I do press <kbd>Q</kbd>, the results all disappear.

Comment: y cant u redirect the output to a file..

Comment: @Rajeev but I will have so many files? I don't like them. I think just print after in the terminal better.

Comment: Did one of the answers work for you?  If so, you should accept it.

Answer (score 20):

This happens because Git is outputting it through a pager. Instead, use:

```
git --no-pager diff
```

It is set to use a pager by the default configuration, and you can change this default to use `cat` instead to prevent you from having to type `--no-pager` with `git config --global core.pager cat`. You can read more in the documentation [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-config).

---

Outputting to `STDOUT` and through a pager is much more complicated and requires tools beyond the scope of regular Unix redirection and pipes.
You can redirect the output to `STDERR` with `tee` and pipe to `less`, which gives the illusion of you want. Note this is a hack and abuses the idea of `STDERR`

```
git diff | tee /dev/stderr | less
```

You may want to make this an alias if you intend on using it frequently.

Comment: @mygoare sorry I put it in the wrong order, see update answer.

Comment: it works, but I can't use j,k to move, the result print out all. I'd like that occur after press q

Comment: @mygoare see updated answer, I only just now understand what you are wanting

Answer (score 16):

What you're experiencing is due to `git` piping the output through a pager, generally `less`.  By default, `less` will send terminal initialization and deinitialization sequences, and the deinitialization sequence can cause the screen to clear.

To stop that behavior, you can either set up something different via [git config core.pager](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corepager), or, more than likely, you have a `LESS` environment variable setup and `git` is just using that.  In this case, you'd want to include the `X` option in your `LESS` environment variable.  `-X` is the same as `--no-init`, which causes `less` to stop outputting the deinitialization sequence to the screen, which will stop it from being cleared.  By default, when `git` sees that `LESS` has not been set, it defaults to `FRX`, which includes the option to keep the screen from clearing.

In general, I don't like `less` disappearing with the contents either. I typically set my `LESS` environment variable to `eFRX`:

```
export LESS=eFRX
```

The `e` is a way to exit when I hit the end of the file and try to page past it.  The `F` says to just exit if there is only one screens worth of content. The `R` helps to interpret ANSI color codes (you'll want that for `git diff`), and the `X` makes it stop clearing the screen before exiting.

It will make you happier with some other programs that use `less` too.

Comment: I think this answers the original question more succinctly. The other answer says "why" the diff disappears but this one tells us "how" to stop that happening in the most economical fashion.

Comment: This was the default behavior for `less` on linux mint, didn't know how good I had it until I had to use a mac for work. This solution is superior to TRENT's as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Just my two cents: the `e` option is abbr flag for `--quit-at-eof`. With this option, you can quit the less page when scrolling to the last line without pressing `q`. `e` and `E` is slightly different but not much.